# "Type is invalid for use as a key column in an index."

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm trying to create a table in SQL using the following code:

```
CREATE TABLE pokemon
(
    Number     INTEGER,
    [Name]     TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
    Type_1     TEXT,
    Type_2     TEXT,
    Total      INTEGER,
    HP         INTEGER,
    Attack     INTEGER,
    Defense    INTEGER,
    Sp_Atk     INTEGER,
    Sp_Def     INTEGER,
    Speed      INTEGER,
    Generation INTEGER,
    Legendary  TEXT
);
```

I get this error:

> Column 'Name' in table 'pokemon' is of a type that is invalid for use as a key column in an index.

Basically, I just want to create a table with these columns.

I got the full code off of the following link, if that means anything:
https://gist.github.com/pamelafox/26b9357c6120d3d0d27c2b90c950e8c6

Comment: As a general rule primary keys are short values (an INT, a BIGINT, a short VARCHAR) where it's easy to compute uniqueness. A `TEXT` column can be very long and MySQL prefers to avoid such an expensive verification every time you insert or update the table. Use something simpler for the PK, not a TEXT column.

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: The key has to be on a unique non-null column, probably `Number` ideally should be declared `not null` and `primary key`

Answer (score 0):

`TEXT` is a deprecated type in SQL Server.  Use a reasonable type:

```
CREATE TABLE pokemon
(
    Number     INTEGER,
    Name       VARCHAR(255) PRIMARY KEY,
    Type_1     VARCHAR(255),
    Type_2     VARCHAR(255),
    Total      INTEGER,
    HP         INTEGER,
    Attack     INTEGER,
    Defense    INTEGER,
    Sp_Atk     INTEGER,
    Sp_Def     INTEGER,
    Speed      INTEGER,
    Generation INTEGER,
    Legendary  VARCHAR(255)
);
```

You might want `NVARCHAR()` intead.

Notes:

- I would strongly recommend using the `number` or an `identity` column for the primary key.  Integers are more efficient than strings for foreign keys.
- The `255` is made up.  Adjust as appropriate for your data.